# Why my combobox count is 0?

Tags: asp.net, combobox, telerik, rad-controls, radcombobox

Why the count of items in my [ComboBox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx) is always 0 although the datasource of this combobox has data !!

---

```
<div align="right" dir="rtl">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_contactListName" runat="server" Text="Menu Name :" CssClass="span"></asp:Label>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddl_contactList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="False"
            CollapseDelay="0" Culture="ar-EG" ExpandDelay="0" Filter="StartsWith" ItemsPerRequest="10"
            MarkFirstMatch="true" Skin="Outlook" EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="True" EmptyMessage="-New Menu-"
            ShowMoreResultsBox="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_contactList_SelectedIndexChanged"
            EnableVirtualScrolling="True" DataTextField="list_desc" DataValueField="list_code"
            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" EnableViewState="true" Width="300px">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </div>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetContactListsByDep"
            TypeName="SendSMS_EmailModule.ContactList">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="year" SessionField="year" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="main_code" SessionField="main_code" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: How are you getting the count?

Comment: Make sure you get the count after the combo box has been bound

Comment: ddl_contactList.Items.Count()

Comment: there's no thing related to this combobox in pageload because i use `DatasourceID`

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious... have you queried the data (directly from the db) with the exact parms you are using in the page datasource?

Comment: yes i did and i find the source has data

Comment: the method i use brings data

Answer (score 3):

The property value of of Rad combo "EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand=True" here.This property load all the data on demand. So when you click on your combobox it will load the data in it untill that it is empty. If you do not want to make your combo on demand then Make that property false. By doing that you will get the count directly.

If you want to keep that EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand property to True. you can use ItemDataBound event of the Rad Combo. By using it  you can change the Item's Text and Value properties as well as modify its Attributes collection based on the DataItem

You will find more details at [telerik rad combo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx). Let me know if you want more detail on this.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should call DataBind() before you call Count().

```
ddl_contactList.DataBind();
ddl_contactList.Items.Count();
```

Comment: hmmm i use `DataSourceId` so why should i bind again ??

Comment: DataSourceId will come into effect in the `PreRender` event in the page lifecycle, and your `.Count()` call is happening in `Page_Load` which happens before that, so manually calling `.DataBind()` causes it to databind earlier, when you need it.  Alternatively you could try to move your `.Count()` to the `PreRender` event

Comment: @Henk Mollema: which part ??

Comment: I need to try to get the count on a `button` and i write your code in my `page_load()` but always the count is zero .

Comment: @just_name do you want to call Count() when you click a button or when your page is loaded?

Comment: `ddl_contactList.DataBind();
ddl_contactList.Items.Count();`

Comment: Use this code:  
`ddl_contactList.DataBind();`  
`int itemCount = ddl_contactList.Items.Count();`  

Set a breakpoint to the second line, debug the project and check what value `itemCount` is set to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19877/discussion-between-henk-mollema-and-just-name)

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting the Count as Zero on Page Load.

If that's the case it is because the page load event hits before the ComboBox is populated. An easier way is to populate the items on Page Load itself.

(This code is untested)

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
 using(var context = new Entities())
 {
   foreach(var item in context.Employee)
   {
      RadComboBox1.Items.Add(new RadListBoxItem(item.Name, item.ID.ToString()));
   }
 }
}
//Here you can get the count.
```